# How do I separate existing class variables in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have an existing class hierarchy that makes use of both class variables and class instance variables. The fact that class variables are shared among all child classes was desirable because I have some common data, but now I need to split that shared data among other branches of the inheritance hierarchy.

This is roughly how it looks and works now:

```
class Base
   @@common = ''
   @per_child = ''
   def self.show
      "base: #{@@common}; me: #{@per_child}"
   end
   def self.set(val)
     @per_child = val
   end
   def self.set_all(val)
     @@common = val
   end
end

class Child1 < Base; set "first child"; end
class Child2 < Base; set "second child"; end

Base.set_all('core')
puts "[Child1] #{Child1.show}"
puts "[Child2] #{Child2.show}"
```

Output:

```
[Child1] base: core; me: first child
[Child2] base: core; me: second child
```

This is exactly what I wanted until now. Now, I'm trying to duplicate the behavior of the `Base` class without duplicating the code. Something like the following:

```
# Same "Base" class as above
class Base1 < Base; end
class Base2 < Base; end

class Child1 < Base1; set "first child"; end
class Child2 < Base1; set "second child"; end
class Child3 < Base2; set "third child"; end
class Child4 < Base2; set "fourth child"; end

Base1.set_all('first base')
Base2.set_all('second base')

puts "[Child1] #{Child1.show}"
puts "[Child2] #{Child2.show}"
puts "[Child3] #{Child3.show}"
puts "[Child4] #{Child4.show}"
```

Obviously the output of the above is:

```
[Child1] base: second base; me: first child
[Child2] base: second base; me: second child
[Child3] base: second base; me: third child
[Child4] base: second base; me: fourth child
```

But I want to modify the definition of `Base1` and `Base2` (and `Base` if needed) such that the output is:

```
[Child1] base: first base; me: first child
[Child2] base: first base; me: second child
[Child3] base: second base; me: third child
[Child4] base: second base; me: fourth child
```

I understand why it's behaving the way it is, but I'm not sure how to get the behavior I'm looking for, with `@@common` now a class variable of the `Base1` and `Base2` classes without having to define it in more places than `Base`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a second shot at this based on feedback from my first answer. This abstracts class variable hierarchy behavior. I hope it helps in some way.

```
module BaseBehavior
  def self.included(base)
    base.send(:extend, ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def set_all(val)
      self.send :class_variable_set, class_var_name, val
    end

    def class_var_name
      "@@#{self.name}_base_var"
    end

    def class_var
      if class_variable_defined? class_var_name
        self.send :class_variable_get, class_var_name
      else
        superclass.class_var
      end
    end

   def show
      "base: #{class_var}; me: #{@per_child}"
    end
  end
end

class Base
  include BaseBehavior
  set_all 'core'

  @per_child = ''

  def self.set(val)
    @per_child = val
  end
end

class Base1 < Base
  include BaseBehavior
  set_all 'first base'
end

class Base2 < Base
  include BaseBehavior
  set_all 'second base'
end

class Child1 < Base1; set "first child"; end
class Child2 < Base1; set "second child"; end
class Child3 < Base2; set "third child"; end
class Child4 < Base2; set "fourth child"; end

puts "[Child1] #{Child1.show}"
puts "[Child2] #{Child2.show}"
puts "[Child3] #{Child3.show}"
puts "[Child4] #{Child4.show}"
```

Comment: I appreciate the effort you put into this solution. It's crazy that this kind of contortion is required to do this. Let me see if I understand: you're converting my class variables to functions that reference a class-name-mangled version of the class variable (falling back to looking up in the inheritance hierarchy).

Comment: Yeah, we're setting unique class variables on each class and then falling back to the parent if no class variable is set on the current class. Maybe there's a better way, but it gets a bit gnarly when dealing with class variables on parent/child classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better served using composition instead of inheritance. What this means is setting up objects that communicate with each other explicitly rather than using parent child class relationships. Relying on inheritance often leads to state management issues as you're experiencing here, whereas composition can give you finer control on how state is managed between objects.

For instance:

```
Class Node
  attr_accessor :parent, :name

  def initialize(parent, name)
    @parent = parent
    @name = name
  end

  def show
    "base: #{parent.name} child: #{name}"    
  end
end

parent = Node.new(nil, 'core')
child1 = Node.new(parent, 'child1')
child2 = Node.new(parent, 'child2')
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to use this to accomplish anything like I currently have. The child classes have already been implemented, so going from fully written child classes to instances of some Node class would require a LOT more work than you're showing here. That's why I asked for ways to modify the Base classes, NOT for ways to completely rewrite everything. I think it's reasonable to go from inheritance to mixins maybe (since that's a trivial change in the child classes), but this is entirely different.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll try to add another answer to try and help with the existing implementation.